# How to save a specific length string from a file and work with it in C

Tags: c, file, fgets, fread

So what I'm trying to do is open a file and read it until the end in blocks that are 256 bytes long each time it is called. My dilemma is using `fgets()` or `fread()` to do it.

I was using `fgets()` initially, because it returns a string of the bytes that were read, which is great because I can store that data and work with it. However, in my particular file that I'm reading, the 256 bytes often happen over a more than 2 lines, which is a problem because `fgets()` stops reading when it hits a newline character or the end of the file.

I then thought of using `fread()`, but I don't know how to save the line that I'm referring to with it because `fread()` returns an int referring to the number of elements successfully read (according to its documentation).

I've searched and thought of solutions for a while now and can't find anything that works with my particular scenario. I would like some guidance on how to go about this issue, how would you go about this in my position?

Comment: From what I understand you have two requirements: read in blocks of 256 bytes and keep track of the number of the line you start reading the current block from. Is this correct?

Comment: Actually yes, you're right. I'm also looking to store the string referring to the 256 byte blocks and perform computations on it before the next block of 256 bytes is read is stored into the variable.

Comment: Then you can use `fread()` to read each 256 bytes block and keep a `lineCount` variable to keep track of the number of new line characters you have encountered so far in the input. Since you have to process the blocks already this wouldn't mean much of an overhead in the processing.

Comment: Hey that's a good idea! It's just that I don't know how to store the 256 byte chunks in a variable order to work on them thought if `fread()` returns an int and not a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fread()` to read each 256 bytes block and keep a `lineCount` variable to keep track of the number of new line characters you have encountered so far in the input. Since you have to process the blocks already this wouldn't mean much of an overhead in the processing.

To read a block of 256 chars, which is what I think you are doing, you just need to create a buffer of chars that can hold 256 of them, in other words a char array of size 256.

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 256
char block[BLOCK_SIZE];
```

Then if you check the documentation for [`fread()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm) it shows the following signature:

> Following is the declaration for fread() function.
>
> ```
> size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> - `ptr` -- This is the pointer to a block of memory with a minimum size of size*nmemb bytes.
> - `size` -- This is the size in bytes of each element to be read.
> - `nmemb` -- This is the number of elements, each one with a size of size bytes.
> - `stream` -- This is the pointer to a FILE object that an input stream.

So this means it takes a pointer to the buffer where it will write the read information, the size of each element it's supposed to read, the maximum amount of elements you want it to read and the file pointer. In your case it would be:

```
int read = fread(block, sizeof(char), BLOCK_SIZE, file);
```

This will copy the information from the file to the block array, which you can later process and keep track of the lines. The characters that were read by `fread` are in the `block` array, so the first char in the last read block would be `block[0]`, the second `block[1]` and so on. The returned value in `read` indicates how many elements (in your case chars) were inserted in the array `block` when you call `fread`, this number will be equal to `BLOCK_SIZE` for every call, unless you reach the end of the file or there's an error.

I suggest you read some [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm) for a full example, play a little with the code and do some reading on pointers in C to gain a better understanding of how everything works in general. If you still have questions after that, we can take it from there or you can create a new SO question.

Comment: I see what you're saying, it makes a lot of sense. I'm just a little confused about how you would access `fread()`'s written string information from the `read` variable if it's an `int` and not a string? For instance, if I wanted to print the written block, how would I do it using `read`? Could I do `printf("%s", read);`?

Comment: @Karysto: Your confusion seems to be stemming from the idea you need to use the return value of read().  You pass the pointer to the buffer as a parameter to read() and the function will fill the buffer to which you gave the pointer.  You then process **the buffer**, not the character count, which is returned.

Comment: @MrWonderful @juan.facorro Both of you are awesome! I haven't tried it yet, but it makes complete sense now. I was definitely fixated on the idea of using the return value of `fread()` and processing that instead. Does this mean that the buffer is assigned a new value each time a new block is read?

Comment: @juan.facorro I was definitely confused with the documentation of `fread()`, I thought that the first parameter was a pointer to the memory in bytes needed for each call (more or less like `malloc`), I didn't think that the memory stored the contents to the pointer's address at all. Thank you for clearing that up :)